# insert comboBox value

Tags: sql, winforms, combobox, insert

i try to insert comboBox value in table for this I try this

```
public void additem(string name,int cost,int f)
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Item(ItemName,ItemCost,ItemCategoryIdF)values(@ItemName,@ItemCost,@ItemCategoryIdF)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemName", name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemCost", cost);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemCategoryIdF", f);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

and on button click

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        string name = textBox1.Text;
        int cost = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        int f = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.Selectedvalue);
        Items ab = new Items();
        ab.additem(name, cost, f);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Item Is Inserted!");
        con.Close();
    }
```

this insert successfully but when I check in table f value shows 0 and 0 value inserted in table .. so how I insert selected value from comboBox1in table ?

when I select value from combobox then that value should in f .. suppose in combobox values is chips, sweets, biscuits so if I select biscuit then f value should b 2 because chips for 1 , sweets for 2 and biscuits for 3

updated code but this shows error

```
**Additional information: Cannot bind to the new display member.**
```

value I load in comboxbox

```
 private void Item_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Global.objCon = new SqlConnection(Global.con);      
        Global.sqlquery=("select CategoryId,CategoryName from Category");
        Global.objCon.Open();
        Global.objcmd = new SqlCommand(Global.sqlquery, Global.objCon);
        Global. dr = Global.objcmd.ExecuteReader();
        ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
        while(Global.dr.Read())
        {
            AddItem obj=new AddItem(Convert.ToInt16(Global.dr["CategoryId"]),Global.dr["CategoryName"].ToString());
            arr.Add(obj);
        }
        reader.Close();
        Global.objCon.Close();
        comboBox1.DataSource = arr;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "CategoryName";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Categoryid";


    }
```

any help

Comment: what was the original value of f ? and there is no need to open the sql connection and call ExecuteNonQuery again in you button click event , while you are already doing this in your addItem method.

Comment: f value is come from combo box and ok I comment that execute non query

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 private void Item_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Global.objCon = new SqlConnection(Global.con);      
    Global.sqlquery=("select CategoryId,CategoryName from Category");
    Global.objCon.Open();
    Global.objcmd = new SqlCommand(Global.sqlquery, Global.objCon);
    Global. dr = Global.objcmd.ExecuteReader();
    BindingList<AddItem> arr = new BindingList<AddItem>();
    while(Global.dr.Read())
    {
        AddItem obj=new AddItem(Convert.ToInt16(Global.dr["CategoryId"]),Global.dr["CategoryName"].ToString());
        arr.Add(obj);
    }
    reader.Close();
    Global.objCon.Close();
    comboBox1.DataSource = arr;
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "CategoryName";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "Categoryid";
}
```

Comment: no. I don't want to select index because this start from 0 whereas in database table values are from 1 not from 0 so when I select biscuits value should be 3 ..

Comment: because combobox values are fill from database

Comment: and sorry my bad I told you values are from 0 but I don't want this

Comment: If your combobox values shown are ordered by its values, then you can just add 1 to the selected index, check my answer after update

Comment: no .. may b order or not if value is deleted from category tables(ItemCategoryIdF,ItemCategoryname) (the table from combobox is filled) if values only two like chips ,biscuits and sweets is deleted then ItemCategoryIdF in table is 1 and 3 .. 1 for chips and 3 for biscuits .. so  ?? you select index where I don't want to select index I want to select ItemCategoryIdF  from combobox